# Laravel 5.1 Passing Parameters to Middleware with Route Groups

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, jwt, laravel-5.1

I am trying to implement a JWT library for an API I am working on and I want to be able to wrap my entire API route group in token checks with a small number of exceptions.  The problem I am having is not specific to JWT.

In a controller constructor, when I apply the middleware, I am able to use this syntax to apply jwt.auth to the entire controller and exclude the 'authenticate' endpoint.

```
public function __construct()
    {
       // Apply the jwt.auth middleware to all methods in this controller
       // except for the authenticate method. We don't want to prevent
       // the user from retrieving their token if they don't already have it
       $this->middleware('jwt.auth', ['except' => ['authenticate']]);
    }
```

When I attempt to do the same thing in my route group I cannot get the 'exception' array to pass correctly.  This causes the authenticate method to require a token (which it can't require because it is the endpoint to RETRIEVE the token).

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'jwt.auth', 'except' => ['authenticate']], function()
{
    Route::resource('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController', ['only' => ['index']]);
    Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
});
```

I have a feeling this is a syntax issue, but I cannot find anyone else asking this question and the parser doesn't choke on it, it just doesn't work.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I took a brief look in [laravel/framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework/) and I didn't see support for this. I would suggest using nested `Route::group`'s something like the following.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {

    // Not explicitly behind a middleware
    // However a controller could still have a middleware injected.
    Route::controller('Auth/AuthController');

    // Authenticated Routes
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
        Route::get('secret', 'SecretsController@index');
    });
});
```

Comment: Ahh okay, that should work just fine.  I guess I was looking at it inside-out.  Thanks for clarifying that one for me!

Comment: You forgot to close the "[" in your second group declaration